# Mirth Connect : How to create channel to make HTTP request once in a day

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

Requirement is that we need to download some certificates everyday. For this we have `RESTfull endpoint` in our application and when manually sent request to `RESTfull endpoint`, then certificates are downloaded to our application folder.

Now I am looking to automate it by creating channel in `Mirth`, which will make `HTTP` request the `RESTfull endpoint` every day.

In Mirth channel, `destination` is set to `HTTP sender` and other configuration are done.

But I am not getting about configurations needs to be done for `Source`.

Could any one please suggest what should be the `source` considering the requirement??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easy to do. Just use a JavaScript Reader to return a dummy message. Literally just something like this would work:

```
return 'dummy';
```

The scheduling options available allow you to poll on a certain time interval, poll once a day at a specific time, or even specify a cron expression. Advanced options are also available that allow you to choose which days of the week/month to poll on.

Once you've made your request with the HTTP Sender, I imagine you're going to want to do something with the response. You can use the response from that destination in a *subsequent* destination. For example, you could use a Database Writer to grab values coming from the HTTP response and insert into a table. Or, you could use a Channel Writer to forward the response on to a completely different channel.

Comment: Good solution. Thanks Nick

Comment: Perfect and Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What operation you want to do in your source?You mean to say you are doing your main operation in destination if you want a dummy source means use channel reader.If you elaborate your query I can clearly answer.

Comment: Yes main operation is done in `destination` itself which is `HTTP sender`.  But the `HTTP sender` should make HTTP request only once in day.  I think this we need control in `Source`.  The `channel reader`, does not an option to set interval. Any other options here ??